# R building a package gives different output for vignette

Tags: r, rstudio, package, cran

I am building my first R package and I am facing some problems.
When I run knitr from the Rstudio I get the html vignette as I want it.
However when I run R CMD Build I realize that I have 2 vignettes.

One found in `vignettes/vignette.html` and the other in `inst/doc/vignette.html`

Each one of these gives a different result for the vignette, I tried to check the .Rmd for each and changed them to be the same but I still get different results.
The .Rmd file does not reflect the html file being produced for both vignettes?

Any ideas?

Comment: Without more information, this is difficult to answer. What's different about them? Is the package publicly available (e.g., on Github)? Are calculations different - if so, have you used `set.seed()` to control any random number generation?